# Separating file content using Java

Tags: java, logging

I have a pattern here for example the file begins with a piece of text like "BeginText" and has another like "EndText" , I need the file content that is within those two texts/strings.How can I do this in java, the file content is partly mixed with XML so I cannot use an XML/DOM Parser here since it contains both normal text and XML.Is there a way to do this in Java.

I am considering Java scanners here.If there is any other idea,it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of the built in string methods: "indexOf" and "subString" in the following way:

```
//read file to string using our utility method
String text = readFileContents("pathToTargetFile");

//find start index
int startIndex = text.indexOf("BeginText");

//find end index from start index.
int endIndex = text.indexOf("EndText",startIndex);

//grab the sub string of the text between these two values.
String targetText = text.subString(startIndex,endIndex);





//private utility method, reads file contents and returns as a string
private String readFileContents(String filePath){

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader (new File(filePath)));
String         line = null;
StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String         ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");

while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
    stringBuilder.append( line );
    stringBuilder.append( ls );
}

return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

This Should yield the desired results.

Comment: +1 for the idea.Never thought of treating the entire file as a single string,this would have made my day.Is there by anyway I can include multiple instances of this logic,since there are multiple places where I need to separate the file using the start index and ending index and I don't know how many instances there will be and it cuts down the idea of using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

how about using `String.indexOf(String)`

```
int start = s.indexOf("BeginText");
int end = s.indexOf("EndText");
String content = s.substring(start + "BeginText".length(), end);
```

where `s` is your files content

you would have to check if start is before end and if bothe values aren't `-1`.

Comment: So you are telling me to treat the entire file as a single string?

Answer (score 0):

Use java [pattern matching](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and regular expressions to determine the index of the beginning and ending characters. Once you have those, you have your content.